# NSOutlineView: 'outlineView: heightOfRowByItem:' vs. animating row height

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation, nsoutlineview

I have `NSOutlineView` with rows of variable (in runtime) height. It's simple to change the height immediately with `outlineView: heightOfRowByItem:` method in delegate. But I want to animate row height like during expanding/collapsing animation.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `NSOutlineView` call [noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-SW130) like:

```
// index set with all rows that did change height
NSIndexSet *rows = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
[self.outlineView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:rows];
```

This will animate the rows to the new height as returned by the `outlineView:heightOfRowByItem:` delegate method.

From the documentation:

> For View-based tables, this method will animate.
>   [...]
>   For cell based tables, this method normally doesn't animate. However, it will animate if you call it inside a beginUpdates/endUpdates block.